# Shelf life of liquid malt extract?

Tags: extract

My husband has what appears to be about 46 oz. of what I am guessing is liquid malt extract in a cabinet above our built in microwave.  I know we brought it from our old house when we moved to our present house just over 20 years ago.  I want to throw it out.  I can't imagine it is any good at this age.  Could it possibly be okay?

Answer (score 3):

It could possibly be OK, but is it worth your time to make a beer just to find out whether you've saved $9? Chuck it.

Answer (score 2):

[Briess says 24 months](http://www.brewingwithbriess.com/blog/about/).

So, you're talking about 10 times the recommended shelf life. I'd toss it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read, LME production has come a long way in the last 20-30 years (according to John Palmer of *How to Brew*), and extract back then wasn't very good to begin with. Even if it were still somehow good after 20 years, it probably wouldn't be that great.